# Advanced search page for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search

I have a wordpress site thats related to laptops niche. So I have multiple categories like Display(10inch, 13inch, 15inch...), Processor(AMD, Intel), HDD(120GB, 320GB, 500GB...) etc.

The usual search is not good. I want to create an advanced search page where user can select from options(drop downs/checkboxes) in these different cats and the corresponding search results are displayed.

Any directions about this will be great help (plugins/themes/hacks).

Answer (score 1):

This tut on [adding search by category in WordPress](http://blog.websitestyle.com/index.php/2009/03/12/wp-search-by-category/) should do the trick :)

Comment: I found multiple-category-selection-widget which does the things that I want. Stilllooking for some good hacks.